# jquery replacing and removing variables

Tags: jquery, html

I have replaced chosen replaced and inserted dom elements this way:

```
$(".editLink").click(function () {
    var $temp = $(".editLink").parent().prev().find("label").html();

    var $tempBox = $(".editLink").parent().prev().find("label").replaceWith("<input type='text' name='dataUpdate'/>");

    $tempBox.insertAfter("<input type='submit' value='Update'/>");
});
```

However, changes flicker,..and dont persist. They only persist for one second..(I guess only for the time of the event. How can I make them persist forever ?

UPDATE:

```
<table width="400px">
<form action="/Admin/Update?Length=4" method="post">
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="fadsf">
            fadsf</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="editLink" href="/Admin/MenuManagement?Length=5">Edit</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="deleteLink" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#1"
            href="/Admin/Delete?deleteID=1&amp;unDelete=1" id="1" title="0">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: They persist forever by default. If you get different behavior then something else in your page is also modifying the DOM.

Comment: Could you please provide us you HTML code? It seems like another event callback is reverting changes back.

Comment: make a demo that replicates issue...provided info is not enough to troublleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll guess you suggest they only persist for the time of the event because you are binding to an `<a>` tag which causes the page to reload or navigate somewhere else.  You need to prevent that default behavior like so:

```
$(".editLink").click(function (e) {
   ... other code

   $(e).preventDefault();

   ... other code
});
```

And the documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault

**UPDATE** - Based on the HTML you have now provided

Your HTML does not look valid. You cannot nest a form tag in between a `table` tag and a `tr` tag and expect it to work.  First off, move the form tag outside of the table.  Secondly, close the table with a matching `</table>` tag.  Maybe that will help.

Hope this helps!

Comment: will throw error in jQuery....incorrect implementaion  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @charlietfl updated implementation, thanks for catching that.

Comment: I dont think it matters. I create many forms with each row..I must use it that way

Answer (score 1):

returning false from the click handler will prevent the browser following the url in the href

```
$(".editLink").click(function () {
    var $temp = $(".editLink").parent().prev().find("label").html();

    var $tempBox = $(".editLink").parent().prev().find("label").replaceWith("<input type='text' name='dataUpdate'/>");

    $tempBox.insertAfter("<input type='submit' value='Update'/>");

    return false;
});
```

You can also use event.preventdefault()
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
  $(".editLink").click(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         /* your code*/

  })
```

Comment: I see..thats why i was wrong.. I also use insertAfter..but no button appears ..why is that?

Comment: insertAfter( jQuerySelector)  ....you have a string...not sure what you are trying to do  http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Comment: I am trying to get the element that I replaced, and insert after it another element..A submit button

Comment: I think this is what you want: $("<input type='submit' value='Update'/>").insertAfter($tempBox);

Comment: I am trying to insert this:  $("<input type='submit' value='Update' />").insertAfter($tempBox); ... submit button after the textbox

Comment: The problem is that no textbox appears :(

Comment: put example together how you want html to look